# SQL best practice to cache frequently-used data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm designing a small business intelligence app with a few hundred thousand rows.  Most of my user queries rely upon data from another query that never changes but that is time-intensive.  So ideally, every night when I reload the database with data, I want to run that query once and store the data somewhere, an intermediate table.  Is this the best practice?  Is the TEMP TABLE the best way to do this in Postgres?  Since this serves a web app, and since temp tables expire at the end of a session, I suppose that a session for a web app persists across users and therefore would be adequate for this, i.e. I don't want the query to run once for every app user.  Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use a permanent table and drop it/recreate it once per day?

Comment: I suppose that works -- and then kick that off with a stored procedure after the data is loaded? ... or make the query part of the DDL that load data?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Materialized View:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html

```
create materialized view mv_t1 as select a, b, (a+b) as absum from table_name;
```

Postgres MV's are essentially the same as doing a

```
create table t1 as select * from t2;
```

In that they are "dumb", and have to be fully refreshed. You can set a cronjob to run every day or hour or so to refresh them. Oracle's MV's are quite smarter, and can auto-repopulate certain rows based on updates and inserts.

```
refresh materialized view mv_t1;
```

If you want the MV to be accessible during the time it takes to refresh, you can do this:

```
refresh materialized view concurrently mv_t1;
```

Note that to use the concurrent refresh feature, at least 1 of the columns in the MV has to have a unique constraint (it's how Postgresql keeps track of rows it has refreshed already). Usually this would simply be an `id` column.

It can be helpful to prefix MV's as they can appear to be just normal tables to developers who aren't aware of their purpose. I use `mv_`.

If the schema of the parent table changes, you'll have to recreate the MV if you want it to reflect those changes.
If you're not manually creating the MV (creating through an ORM or other indirect methods), be aware that upon creation it will populate with data, which could take a lot of time depending on the complexity of the query. If you want to create a materialized view with just structure, and manually "refresh" it later on, you can do this:

```
create materialized view m1 as select * from t1 with no data
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the kind of advice I was seeking.

Answer (score 1):

We had a stored procedure that would kick off the first time someone logged into our app for the day that would refresh the data in certain tables. You could do something like that or have a job that runs at  specific time to delete and reload all of the data.